# Is secured WiFi with a publicly available password any safer than open WiFi?

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle

Modern security training take the same principle that sex Ed videos took when I was in school -- scare the viewers into never taking a chance. Our corporate training suggests to never connect to any public WiFi.

While I understand on public unsecured WiFi sends all communications in an unsecured manner; anyone with a laptop can monitor your activity. I know a lot of businesses offer secured guest wifi with the password publicly available.

While it's obvious the business could monitor my web traffic, I'm curious if others could also use the publicly known WiFi password to decrypt my traffic.